# Rotation and resizing of UIView created from collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cgaffinetransform

I have collection view and on tap on its cell uiview is created with coordinates of cell translated to superview. Next I need to resize created uiview to screen size while newly created uiview rotating on 90 degrees:

```
let coord = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
let cellFrameInSuperview:CGRect! = collectionView.convert(coord!.frame, to: self.view)
let imageViewDummy = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: (cellFrameInSuperview?.origin.x)!, y: (cellFrameInSuperview?.origin.y)!, width: cell.videoContainer.coverImageView.frame.size.width, height: cell.videoContainer.coverImageView.frame.size.height))

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
     var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
     transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
     imageViewDummy.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
     imageViewDummy.transform = transform
})
```

But after animation, view is wrongly placed. It should fit full screen

UPDATE:

Working code:

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
            imageViewDummy.center = CGPoint(x: imageViewDummy.frame.size.height / 2, y: imageViewDummy.frame.size.width / 2)
            var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
            imageViewDummy.transform = transform
            imageViewDummy.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        }, completion: {(result: Bool) in

        })
```

Comment: Could you share a picture of the result you are getting?

Comment: Please find screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsxc6k5aj5o9qnl/result.jpg?dl=0 Also autoresize is disabled in IB

Comment: I see, why dont you try in the creation of the imageViewDummy to set the origin coordinates to 0,0? I mean: `let imageViewDummy = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width: cell.videoContainer.coverImageView.frame.size.width, height: cell.videoContainer.coverImageView.frame.size.height))`

Comment: I need effect that created uiview appearing from place (coordinates) of cell